# Should I use staples or attachment for 6/2 cable?

Tags: wiring

I am installing 6/2 Romex cable. I have previously installed 10/2 cable, and have installed larger cable for a subpanel feed. For my 10/2 wire, I still use staples, although it is those strap versions designed for bigger cable. For subpanel feeds, I use single hole metal straps, the same as the existing panel feed.

I can't seem to find a staple rated higher than #10 wire. I guess I could put it under single hole straps, but it would fit loosely, those are not really designed for cable.

Whats the correct answer here?

Comment: How do you intend to feed a subpanel with 6/2?  Combining both neutral and ground on the bare wire?  You haven't been allowed to do that since the Eagles owned the pop charts.  You need 6/3 cable.

Answer (score 4):

You can use metal staples, which give you a bit more size flexibility. Just be sure to go forth gently and not crimp the cable jacket at all.

There are [staples with plastic caps for that size cable](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Briscon-1-3-8-in-x-13-16-in-Plastic-Insulated-Staples-for-Cable-Gray-10-Pack-SN-300-IB-10/202018408), though.

> Secure ... 8/3 - 6/3 non-metallic sheathed cable... to wood framing

Comment: I agree, but my box of bare metal 1/2 staples (shown here): https://www.homedepot.com/p/Southwire-1-2-in-Romex-Metal-Staples-500-Pack-58978501/205717554 say "Secures #14-3, #12-3 or #10-3 Romex cables and other NM cables", IE., #10 max. It does fit, I tried it. I want this install to follow code.

Comment: Are you asking me to find larger metal staples for you? [Here are some](https://www.hardwareandtools.com/gardner-bender-gse-310-13-16-inch-metal-staple-cjfa-6695.html).

Comment: Ah so simply wider does it eh. Thanks muchly.

Comment: Sure. Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) if you're new to how SE sites work.